# Algebraic geometry reference for people with limited background

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

My background in algebra is groups and rings from Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* and field theory from Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*. With this background, can I read any algebraic geometry? Which references should I take a look at?
Thanks.

Comment: Check out Michael Artin's MIT OCW notes.

Comment: @littleO Could you possibly find a link to these notes/the course? All the AG stuff I see on MIT doesn't seem to have anything by Artin, except possibly recommend his text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try taking a look at Mike Artin's MIT OCW notes:

http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.721/index.html

> Goals of the course: When you have completed this course, you will be
>   well prepared for a graduate course in algebraic geometry, and you
>   should be able to read some papers in the subject. For this, it is
>   essential that you become familiar with cohomology. The effort
>   required is worthwhile. Algebraic geometry is usually taught assuming
>   familiarity with commutative algebra. We will try to keep commutative
>   algebra to a minimum. To help make the material accessible, I’ve made
>   some simplifying restrictions: The most important are:
>
> 1. We work exclusively with quasiprojective varieties over the field of complex numbers.
> 2. Theorems will not be stated or proved in their most general form.
> 3. Cohomology is introduced only for modules (aka quasicoherent sheaves).

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a fantastic set of notes complete with exercises.